# Computing and plotting a spectrogram in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, plotting, signal-processing

How can I compute and plot the spectrogram of a signal/time series/data in Mathematica? I have a WAV file, sampled at 44100 samples/second and I want to generate a spectrogram of that data. Something like this:

[image: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_images/specgram_demo.png]

Comment: Mathematica doesn't read MP3 files if I remember correctly. Some other format?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Get a sample sound:

```
snd = ExampleData[{"Sound", "SopranoSaxophone"}];
```

This gives us a `Sound` data structure with a `SampledSoundList` as first element. Extracting the data from it:

```
sndData = snd[[1, 1]];
sndSampleRate = snd[[1, 2]];
```

Plotting the data:

```
ListPlot[sndData, DataRange -> {0, Length[sndData]/sndSampleRate }, 
 ImageSize -> 600, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Amplitude", "", ""}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 14}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Find the lowest amplitude level (used as reference for dB calculations):

```
min = Min[Abs[Fourier[sndData]]];
```

A spectrogram is made by making a DFT of partitions of the sample. The partitions usually have some overlap.

```
partSize = 2500;
offset = 250;
spectroGramData = 
  Take[20*Log10[Abs[Fourier[#]]/min], {2, partSize/2 // Floor}] & /@ 
   Partition[sndData, partSize, offset];
```

Note that I skip the first element of the DFT. This is the mean level. I also show only half of the frequency data. Because of the finite sampling only half of the returned coefficient list contains useful frequency information (up to the Nyquist frequency).

```
MatrixPlot[
  Reverse[spectroGramData\[Transpose]], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  DataRange -> 
    Round[
     {{0, Length[sndData]/sndSampleRate }, 
     {sndSampleRate/partSize, sndSampleRate/2 }}, 
     0.1
    ], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2,  ImageSize -> 800, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency (Hz)", "Time (s)", "", ""}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 12}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A 3D spectrogram (note the different offset value):

```
partSize = 2500;
offset = 2500;
spectroGramData = 
  Take[20*Log10[Abs[Fourier[#]]/min], {2, partSize/2 // Floor}] & /@ 
   Partition[sndData, partSize, offset];

ListPlot3D[spectroGramData\[Transpose], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 DataRange -> 
  Round[{{0, Length[sndData]/sndSampleRate }, {sndSampleRate/partSize,
      sndSampleRate/2}}, 0.1], ImageSize -> 800, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: how about a 3d surface spectrogram? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spectrogram.png
additionally, what is [Transpose]

Comment: `\[Transpose]` is a FullForm version of the transpose symbol that does the same as the function `Transpose`. You'll find all about `Transpose` in Mathematica's electronic manual.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, I haven't seen a function in brackets before so I was uncertain where to look, as things such as @ are hard to find. Addtionally, what is ~Join~ ? I saw it on an answer somewhere.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf It's really not that hard. Just select the `/@` and hit F1, it'll take you to the `Map` page, for which `/@` is the infix form shorthand. `~` can be used to convert a function taking two arguments to an infix function: `Func[arg1,arg2]` ==> `arg1~Func~arg2`. More in many places in the manual, e.g., [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html). By the way, it's better to ask these kinds of things in a comment directly below the answer/question that provoked your question.

Comment: What does the offset mean? Does it mean the step size of the moving window? For example, if I have a list of 8 numbers and the bin size is 4, offset=2 means every time I advance the 4-number wide window, 2 numbers ahead. Is my understanding correct? Thanks :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass Right. BTW version 9 has more tools for making these kinds of plots (see Spectrogram and Periodigram).

Answer (score 22):

The following is a more detailed version of a `Spectrogram` implementation in Mathematica and is part of a larger package that I'm writing in my spare time. I've tried to keep the functionality and output structure similar to MATLAB's (but not entirely). The code is provided at the end of this answer, and I'll jump to the examples now:

First load the package and some example data:

```
<<SignalProcessing`
{data, fs} = {#[[1, 1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} &@ ExampleData[{"Sound", "Apollo11SmallStep"}];
```

`Spectrogram` takes several options such as:

- `WindowFunction` — Hamming, Hanning and rectangular (default) windows are pre-defined and you can extend it to other windows or supply one of your own.
- `WindowLength` — Samples in each segment (default is `Floor[Length[data]]`)
- `OverlapLength` — Samples overlapping with the previous segment (default 50%)
- `FFTLength` (default: `Max[256, 2^pow]` where `pow` is the next power of 2 larger than your segment length) and `SamplingFrequency` are self explanatory

A sample call to `Spectrogram` with the above data would be:

```
{s, f, t} = Spectrogram[data, WindowFunction -> Hamming, WindowLength -> 200, 
   SamplingFrequency -> fs];
```

You can then plot this like in Sjoerd's example (or you can implement a default plot style within `Spectrogram`) to get something like:

[image]

A couple of things that are on my to-do list are to implement the Goertzel algorithm so that you can easily supply a list of frequencies at which the spectrogram needs to be calculated and different plotting schemes for 2D (something like the plot above as default) and waterfall and similar for 3D plots. I'll update this post when I get around to doing that.

---

#### Spectrogram code

```
BeginPackage["SignalProcessing`"];
Unprotect[Spectrogram,Hamming,Hanning,Rectangular];

Begin["`Private`"];
(* Input checks *)
DoubleQ[data_List] := And @@ Function[x, MachineNumberQ[x], Listable][data];

CheckInput::sparse = "The input data must not be sparse!";
CheckInput::nodbl = "The input data must be machine precision!";
CheckInput[x_] := Which[
    Head[x] === SparseArray, Message[CheckInput::sparse],
    ! DoubleQ[x], Message[CheckInput::nodbl],
    True, True
]

(* Window functions *)
Rectangular = UnitStep[Range[#]] &;
Hanning = 0.5 (1 - Cos[2 Pi Range[0, #-1]/(#-1)]) &;
Hamming = 0.54 - 0.46 Cos[2 Pi Range[0, #-1]/(#-1)] &;

(* Spectrogram code *)
Spectrogram[data_List, opts : OptionsPattern[{
    WindowFunction -> Rectangular, WindowLength :> Floor[Length[data]/8],
    OverlapLength -> {}, FFTLength -> {}, SamplingFrequency -> 1}]] := 
    Module[{
        x = Developer`ToPackedArray[data], len = Length[data], win, seg, 
        olap, nfft, fs, spectra, time, freq},
        (* parameters *)
        seg = OptionValue[WindowLength];
        olap = If[# === {}, Floor[seg/2], #] &@OptionValue[OverlapLength];
        nfft = If[# === {}, Max[2^Ceiling[Log2[seg]], 256], #] &@ OptionValue[FFTLength];
        win = OptionValue[WindowFunction];
        fs = OptionValue[SamplingFrequency];
        (* output *)
        time = Range[0, len]/fs;
        freq = fs Range[0, nfft/2]/nfft ;
        spectra = Take[Abs[Fourier[PadRight[#*win[seg], nfft], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]] & /@ 
            Partition[x, seg, seg - olap, {1, -1}] // Transpose, Floor[nfft/2] + 1];

        {spectra, freq, time}
    ] /; CheckInput[data]
End[];

Protect[Spectrogram,Hamming,Hanning,Rectangular];
EndPackage[];
```

Comment: You have the frequency start at 0 Hz, but that can't be true. The lowest frequency is determined by the length of your window.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The first DFT bin (and the frequencies it spans) contributes to the "mean". You chose to discard it, I didn't. AFAIK it's not customary to throw it out when plotting.

Comment: This is not about the first bin *per se*.  It's about making your data range fit correctly. If your  window length is short the lowest assignable frequency is not negligible and the frequency values for *all* the bins except the last one experience a shift wrt the values you assign them. The second bin the most of course.

Comment: BTW there's no need to provide `Fourier` with a data list whose length is a power of 2. DFT implementations are usually faster when this is the case (I haven't tested this on MMA), but speed doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Comment: @Sjoerd That's a labeling convention — depends on whether you choose to place the tick mark at the bin center or at the ends. Bin center is also very common and in that case, it would start at half the bin width.  I'm aware that Fourier doesn't need a list that's a power of 2, but you'd be hard pressed to find a signal processing application/paper that doesn't use a power of 2 — probably relics from the past, but is convention. Perhaps I could add another option that uses the actual length instead of padding.

Comment: I'm not talking about bin centres. If you're examining your sound data in pieces of 1000 samples at a time and with a sample rate of 20 kHz the lowest representable frequency will be 20 Hz. That's what should be the lowest part of the plot (or the second lowest in your case). If you let it start at 0 every step in your spectrogram will be slightly mislabeled.

Comment: @Sjoerd Aha! I now get what you're saying. The frequencies in my output `f` are correct (2nd bin is about 21.5ish), but since I set the range from `Min[f]` to `Max[f]`, it stretches the labeling from the _left_ end of the first bin (if you consider it a rectangle) to the _right_ end of the last bin instead of the left end of the last bin. So while I don't think that starting from 20 (or whatever it is) will fix this (it'll have the same subtle misalignment), I agree that it needs to be fixed. I hadn't gotten around to implementing a custom plot of my own and just quickly used yours :)

Comment: How do you know things like "sndSampleRate = snd[[1, 2]];"? WAV have 10 different possible codecs, all with different conventions. How do you figure out imaginary components?

Comment: @TylerDurden This is not a library to support every codec on earth. I was using example data which has a specific format.

Answer (score 14):

Version 9 has introduced several signal processing functions and `Spectrogram` is now a built-in function. You can simply do:

```
{data, fs} = {#[[1, 1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} &@ExampleData[{"Sound", "Apollo11SmallStep"}];
Spectrogram[data, SampleRate -> fs, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    FrameLabel -> {"Frequency (Hz)", "Time (s)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I think you inverted "Frequency" and "Time" in the `FrameLabel` (the capture is correct).

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica can plot spectrograms using the [`Spectrogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Spectrogram.html) function or the [`SpectrogramArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SpectrogramArray.html) function, or the [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fourier.html) function -- it is very general and powerful. [Here are some examples of audio spectrograms](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AudioSpectrogram/) from the Wolfram demonstration site and [here is a discussion on Mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/computing-and-plotting-a-spectrogram-in-mathematica?lq=1) of the process of taking spectrograms of audio. To use mp3s you will need to convert them to .wav files, which can be done using a program like [`Audacity`](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) or Quicktime (or many others). If your final goal is to plot spectrograms, Audacity (or other free software) might be more appropriate. What you would gain in Mathematica is the ability to control the analysis in complete detail -- but this would not be automatic or trivial, it would take some knowledge of how the spectral functions work.