# How to get the frequency information of an mp3 audio?

Tags: sound

I have:

```
music = Import["http://www.qlcoder.com/uploads/145425353234642.mp3", "mp3"]
```

Then I get:

[image]

But what I want to get is `F(t)=x Hz`(means in `t`, the frequency is x Hz). Then how to get that?

Comment: What if there are superimposed sounds of multiple frequencies (as is almost always the case)?  Then a simple `frequency(t)` doesn't make sense.  You may want to compute a spectrogram: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/computing-and-plotting-a-spectrogram-in-mathematica

Comment: If you know for sure that there is only a single (possibly amplitude and frequency modulated) sine oscillator active (e.g. $f(t)=a(t)sin(\omega(t)),\omega(t)=\omega_0 + \int_0^t 2\pi f(s) ds$), then you can see your waveform as the real part of a complex (as in complex numbers) oscillator. You can then use a Hilbert transform (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms)) to get the corresponding imaginary part of that oscillator and use this to reconstruct $a(t)$ and $f(t)$ (which is just $\frac{d\omega(t)}{dt}$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duration = 9.95265 sec, frequency in Hz on x axis:

```
music = Import["http://www.qlcoder.com/uploads/145425353234642.mp3", "mp3"];
amps = music[[1, 1, 1, All]];
namps = Length@amps; (* namps = 438912 corresponds to 9.95265 sec *)

sr = 44100; (* your sampling rate in Hz *)
inc = sr/namps; (* increment *)
freq = Table[f, {f, 0, sr - inc, inc}] // N;

y = Abs@Fourier[amps, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
data = Transpose[{freq, y}];

fmax = 3000; (* you can go up to Nyquist frequence = max frequency = 22050 Hz *)

ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thickness[0.002]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Amplitude", ""}, {"f (Hz)", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 20, 
   FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, PlotRange -> {{0, fmax}, All}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get the peak frequency value data somehow?

Answer (score 13):

You can see the spectrum of the first note played, (first 40000 points)

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 {#, # PeakDetect[#, 5, 10^-2]} &@
  Abs@Fourier@music[[1, 1, 1, 1 ;; 40000]]
 , Joined -> {True, False}
 , PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red}
 , Filling -> Axis
 , PlotRange -> {{100, 1000}, All}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But beware that the scaling  is not in Hertz here
To get the scaling correct use:

```
sft[d_, sr_] := Block[{n, ft, fy},
  n = Length[d];
  fy = Take[N@Abs[Fourier[d]], n/2];
  ft = N@Range[0, n/2 - 1] sr/n;
  SortBy[First]@Transpose[{ft, fy}]
  ]

ListLogLogPlot[
 {#, Part[#, 
     Flatten@Position[PeakDetect[#[[All, 2]], 5, 10^-2], 1]]} &@
  sft[music[[1, 1, 1, 1 ;; 40000]], music[[1, 2]]]
 , Joined -> {True, False}
 , PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red}
 , Filling -> Axis
 , PlotRange -> {{100, 1000}, All}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To see the peaks of the first two notes:

```
Part[#, Flatten@Position[PeakDetect[#[[All, 2]], 5, 10^-2], 1]] &@
 sft[music[[1, 1, 1, 1 ;; 40000]], music[[1, 2]]]
```

> ```
>  {{174.195, 4.61849}, {350.595, 5.65904}, {524.79, 3.73059}}
> ```

```
Part[#, Flatten@Position[PeakDetect[#[[All, 2]], 5, 10^-2], 1]] &@
 sft[music[[1, 1, 1, 40001 ;; 70000]], music[[1, 2]]]
```

> ```
> {{164.64, 3.93114}, {330.75, 3.66594}, {495.39, 1.70307}, {660.03, 4.29606}, {826.14, 1.9469}}
> ```