# For what range of frequencies is the Fourier function defined?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am interested in evaluating the discrete Fourier transform for a list of data. The problem is the results given by the function `Fourier` depends on the length of the data.

For example, if the list of data is simply `Table[Sin[20 π t], {t, 0, 10, x}]` for different values of `x` I will obtain the same shape from `Fourier` when I plot the obtained numbers but the values on the $x$ axis will change.

For $x=0.001$ I will get:

[image: m1]

But for $x=0.01$ I get:

[image: different result]

Comment: Possible duplicates: [105439](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105439/discrete-fourier-transform-help-on-how-to-convert-x-axis-in-to-the-frequency-wh), [33149](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33149/frequencies-represented-in-a-dft-list-fourier) and [44237](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44237/correct-fourier-scaling-and-high-resolution-frequency-identification)

Comment: The answer to your question is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/287612/143764).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The x axis of your plot has no meaning - it is simply the index of the value: The finer the data in your original table, the finer the frequency resolution and therefore the bigger the number of values in your output.

You can transform the axes however: The frequency spacing $\delta f$ and total bandwidth $\Delta f$ is defined the following way:

$\delta f=\frac{1}{\Delta t}$

$\Delta f=\frac{1}{\delta t},$

where $\delta t$ is the time domain spacing and $\Delta t$ is the total time span of the data.

**Note**: Despite the many duplicates (see comments), I thought it would be nice to have the relations written down somewhere without the need to extract them from code (as far as I could tell, they're not in any of the duplicates). It might be better to move this answer to one of the duplicates - if so, to which one should I move this?