# Plotting a 2D grid "spectrogram" from a large .csv file

Tags: plotting, data, csv-format

I'm aware of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/computing-and-plotting-a-spectrogram-in-mathematica) here that uses `MatrixPlot` to plot the spectrogram of a sound file, but it's too complicated for me to understand, unfortunately.

My file consists of 1000 lines and several thousand columns of data that represent the intensity of a signal, taken at identical time ticks after a trigger signal has occurred. As an example, the first few columns and lines look like this:

```
0, -0.028346,   -0.028346,  -0.028346
1, -0.028346,   -0.028346,  -0.028346
2, -0.028346,   -0.028346,  -0.028346
3, -0.028346,   -0.028346,  -0.028346
4, -0.027056,   -0.027056,  -0.028346
```

My idea was to:

- Import my file with `mydata = Import["myfile.csv", "CSV"]`
- determine the minimum and maximum of this data to have reference values with
  `min = Min[Abs[data]];` and `max=Max[Abs[data]]`
- make a plot as follows: every column should be represented by a line of dots/pixels, color-coded to represent the intensity of the signal (What function would I use here?)
- stack all these lines, aligned with each other, on top of each other, such that the time/columns from `mydata` basically goes from bottom to top

Am I on the right track or should I use something else instead?

EDIT: found an easy answer myself that I will post below.

Comment: Are you sure your time would not be better spent trying to understand the existing solution, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel? Also, you will want to include a complete data set if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing and plotting a spectrogram in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4017/computing-and-plotting-a-spectrogram-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a solution that I found myself that is rather easy to implement and can be adapted to your needs.

Import your data with

```
data = Import["myfile.csv"];
```

Then, simply use `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`

```
ArrayPlot[data,
ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"]),
ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

One can certainly play around with color parameters, graphic scaling etc., but that is quite individually different, so I'll omit it here and just share the image that I got out of my dataset. The two artifact lines are due to some empty columns in my dataset.

[image: Mode behaviour of a free-running laser over approx. 30 min]